# How can a web application/API connect and transmit data to a console application via ssl/tls connection

Tags: ssl, https, asp.net-web-api2, console-application, tls1.2

I have a console application and a web api, both using .net 4.7.2
My console application opens a connection port to listen using ssl/tls.
I want from web api to be able to connect to that console application and be able to send/receive data.
When deployed, these two applications will be installed separately on different machines.
So is there any way for the web api to call the console application via the opened ip and ssl/tls port?

I searched a lot but only found instructions on how to call from console to web api. but what I want is the opposite.
I also found a way to be able to call from the web api, which is to create an http server in the console application to listen for requests as follows:

```
 HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:12345/");
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                
                HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                string response = "Hello from Windows Form!";
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                // send respone
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                context.Response.Close();
            }
```

But I think it is possible to connect to via existing ssl/tls instead of having to create an http server.

Any ideas for these?

Comment: I would use SSH for this. Indeed I have used SSH for this.

Comment: If possible, I recommend using .net core for the console app and self-hosting asp.net. If core isn't an option, hosting an http listener is your best bet. A raw ssl/tls server is much more complex.